# CSS first-letter formatting creates gap between first and second line

Tags: css, line, paragraph, letter

When I use the css **::first-letter** to increase the font in the following way:

```
p:first-letter {
    font-size: 400%;
}
```

It creates a gap between the first and the second line of the paragraph. Can you please suggest a solution to avoid this gap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is located in `line-height`. If you wonder how line height actually works, I recommend you to read this article: http://joshnh.com/weblog/how-does-line-height-actually-work

```css
p {
  padding: 15px;
}
p:first-letter {
  font-size: 400%;
  line-height: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. **line-height: 0;** solved the problem

Answer (score 3):

That's because they are aligned by their baseline, an the descenders in a large font size are much higher.

A good way to treat large first letters is to treat them as float elements (i.e. *inside* the text block) and adjust their height to the used regular font and font-size, like this:

```css
p:first-letter {
  font-size: 500%;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<p class="first-letter">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a,</p>
```